# Flutter: Importing image Url from Network error

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, state-management

Hello I am new to flutter and was doing an ecommerce app while importing images URLs from firebase SOMETIMES while calling the "Image.network" gives me this error but only sometimes, and with different picture URLs(every time it is random and sometimes it loads every picture)
which is weird I don't know how to solve it .
[image]

Here is the exception it gives.

[image]

Here is mobile emulator picture

[image]

as U can see it's different every time.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a few solutions that people have come up with. On the Flutter GitHub issues page this "hack" appears to have helped some people:

[Potential Solution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25107#issuecomment-655655719)